# SQL to query rows that do not have a value

Tags: sql

I am trying to query all rows of a "parts" table even if their number ordered is none. This is giving me a problem because when the number ordered is not on the "order_line" table it does not show the item as having none (which is essentially the reason for this question in the assignment)

Here is my sql for to find all of the parts with number ordered:

```
    SELECT PART.PART_NUM,
  PART.DESCRIPTION,
  PART.ON_HAND,
  PART.PRICE,
  ORDERS.ORDER_NUM,
  ORDER_LINE.NUM_ORDERED
FROM PART
INNER JOIN ORDER_LINE
ON PART.PART_NUM = ORDER_LINE.PART_NUM
INNER JOIN ORDERS
ON ORDER_LINE.ORDER_NUM = ORDERS.ORDER_NUM
ORDER BY PART.PART_NUM
```

This is for school so if you could just point me in the right direction that would be great. Hope this made sense..

Comment: You need to use an outer join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, when you specify INNER JOIN it means that for a row to be in the result set it must be made up of an existing row from the left-hand side of the JOIN *and* an existing row from the right-hand side.

But INNER JOIN is not the only way to JOIN tables.  You can also use LEFT or RIGHT OUTER JOIN, which requires only one of the two tables to have a row in it (the values that would have come from the other side of the JOIN are all NULL in the result set).  There is even a FULL OUTER JOIN, which requires a row from *either* of the two sides.

Look up OUTER JOIN in your documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will look into the different types of joins clearly missing some comprehension on the differences.

Answer (score 3):

use 'left outer join' in place of 'inner join' for the order_line table

EDIT: as pointed out by Martin, you need to replace both 'inner join's with 'left outer join'

Comment: That will be converted back to an inner join by the next join along if that's the only change made.

Comment: thanx Martin - I missed that - fixed my answer